# How to access selected file name in Panel Fileinput widget?

Tags: python, file-io, widget, panel

I am using python Panel Fileinput widget to upload a file. Upload works and I need to save uploaded data with same filename, but I can'n find way to access uploaded file name.

```py
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

file_input = pn.widgets.FileInput()
file_input
```

After selecting file the widget displays filename next to it, but filename is not included in objects
[image]

```py
file_input.get_param_values()
```

These are parameters of the sample file 'test.txt'

```py
[('align', 'start'),
 ('aspect_ratio', None),
 ('background', None),
 ('css_classes', None),
 ('disabled', False),
 ('height', None),
 ('height_policy', 'auto'),
 ('margin', (5, 10)),
 ('max_height', None),
 ('max_width', None),
 ('mime_type', 'text/plain'),
 ('min_height', None),
 ('min_width', None),
 ('name', ''),
 ('sizing_mode', None),
 ('value', b''),
 ('width', None),
 ('width_policy', 'auto')]
```

Need: file_input.filename variable for accessing uploaded file name.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of panel are you using? 
If I do this with panel 0.6.2, it works for me:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

file_input = pn.widgets.FileInput()
file_input

file_input.get_param_values()
```

Before I select a file, there's already the following attributes:

> [('filename', None), 
>   ('value', None), ]

And after selecting a file, I see the following attributes:

> [('filename', 'Screenshot 2019-04-04 at 18.42.55.png'), 
>   ('value', content of the image file)]

So getting the filename, should just be:

```
file_input.filename
```

And getting the file, should be:

```
file_input.value
```

Comment: For me, on version 0.7.0, repeating exactly your steps, I get a `file_input.filename` equal to None. I get the right `file_input.value` though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/955), certainly with panel 0.7.0 and bokeh 1.4.0 (probably due to some change in bokeh - did not investigate).
Fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/pull/956).